# Changing the upload limit in php

Tags: php

I am developing a CMS where the clients will need to upload files larger than 2mb - up to 10mb at least. I have changed the details in the php.ini file and I cannot see anywhere else that the problem might be. Any help?

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I recommend changing (assuming Apache & PHP):

I've found this works well for up to about 30mb attachments

### PHP Settings

- max`_execution`_time = 120
- max`_input`_time = 120
- memory_limit = 30M
- post`_max`_size = 30M
- upload`_max`_filesize 30M
- file_uploads = On *(although it sounds like you already have this turned)*

### Apache Settings

- LimitRequestBody 31457280

Answer (score 2):

You need to set upload_max_filesize, post_max_size and memory_limit appropriately. post_max_size must be larger than upload_max_filesize, because there needs to be memory allocated for the request headers as well as the file payload.

Answer (score 2):

In your `php.ini`:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 50M
```

What errors are you getting in your error log once these have been done? Is it possible that your uploaded file is running foul of the memory limit on the script?

You can set the memory limit higher for this particular script by including the following line in your script:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","75M");
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you changed `upload_max_filesize` AND `post_max_size`

Answer (score -1):

As long as you have restarted your web service (ie apache) then the changes  should take  effect, however if you are developing for anyone other then yourself then instead of changing the php.ini I would add this to the upload script:

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
```

as some people may not be able to modify php.ini this will change it just for the page it is on.