# How to increase my upload limit in php

Tags: php

I read so many articles out there in the internet and found that to change the php.ini file to upgrade the upload limit. But I do all the suffs and cant upload more than 10mb of files or so.

I am trying to add a feature to upload video file through the front end for users. But failed for some reason

Is there any other way to do it. Or is it because it is a video file or some thing like that

Comment: Duplicate / Related (with answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997511/php-uploads-limit-for-scanning/1997529#1997529 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578190/can-file-uploads-time-out-in-php/578226#578226 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197419/changing-the-upload-limit-in-php/197458#197458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have (in php.ini, .htaccess, etc.):

- increased `post_max_size` to at least twice the max file size that you might need to upload
- increased `upload_max_filesize` to the max file size that you might want to upload
- increased `memory_limit` to something bigger than `post_max_size`

Answer (score 1):

On top of setting php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
post_max_size = 200M
```

I owuld look into a flash uploader like [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/). It will make your life much easier trust me.

Comment: thanks I am using that uploadify now. But the file limit is what restricting me from doing the upload process

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing the php.ini, are you restarting the webserver so that the changes take effect (if using mod_php)?  Does the webserver itself have any restrictions set?

Comment: I have to check it with the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but in my php.ini I have `upload_max_filesize = 200M` and I have `post_max_size = 200M`

I also set `max_execution_time = 3000`  If this is set too low, it'll cut off while the user is still uploading.
You should also bump up `max_input_time` and `memory_limit`