# PHP moving a file that is more the 1 MB

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I am trying to copy a file that has a max from localhost and move it to a new location (Example: move it to my project folder). My code is working, however, if I try to move a file that is 1 MB or more, it doesn't work. I was hoping that some could help me please.

This is my code.

```
$file = $_FILES["file_to_upload"]["name"];
$temp_name = $_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name'];

if (!empty($file)) {

    $location = '../files/';
    if (move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location . $file)) {

    } else {
        echo 'There was a problem moving the file';
    }
} else {
    echo 'You did not select a file.';
}
```

Comment: What does 'it doesn't work' mean? What errors do you get? Have you checked your php.ini settings which often limit the maximum size of uploads?

Comment: Have you checked your config file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase my upload limit in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612459/how-to-increase-my-upload-limit-in-php)

Comment: I do not get a errors message, except the error message I create for myself if the file didn't get move. "There was a problem moving the file". And no I have not check php.ini settings. I am new to php, so I really don't have much idea about php.ini.

Comment: Well, do these things. As to error messages, most php calls return error statuses, there is also an web server error log you should be checking.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the POST sizes in your `php.ini` file.

You can see what your current POST sizes are by doing:

```
echo ini_get('upload-max-filesize'), ini_get('post-max-size');
```

**An Example of what to change in your php.ini file**

```
post_max_size=50M
upload_max_filesize=50M
```

Where `50M` means 50 megabytes.